# Loop through array inside an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I've got this array

```
var enemy = {
'level1' : {
    creature :
    {
        creature_name : {
             'Goblin' : {
                info: {
                    'c_name' : 'Goblin',
                    'HP' : '20',
                    'damage' : '3',
                    'loot' : [
                        {name: 'a wooden sword'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 2}, 
                        {name: 'a golden necklace', item: 'amulet' , value: 1},
                        {name: 'a pair of boots'  , item: 'boots'  , value: 1},
                        {name: 'some cloth legs'  , item: 'legs'  , value: 1},
                        {name: 'a cloth helmet'   , item: 'helm'  , value: 1}
                    ]
                }
             },
             'Cow' : {
                info: {
                    'c_name' : 'Cow',
                    'HP' : '10',
                    'damage' : '1',
                    'loot' : [
                        {name: 'bell'              , item: 'weapon'  , value: 0}, 
                        {name: 'cow hide cloak'    , item: 'cape'  , value: 1}, 
                        {name: 'a wooden sword'    , item: 'weapon'  , value: 2}, 
                        {name: 'a golden necklace' , item: 'amulet' , value: 1},
                    ]
                }
             },
             'Dragon' : {
                info: {
                    'c_name' : 'Dragon',
                    'HP' : '100',
                    'damage' : '5',
                    'loot' : [
                        {name: 'an almighty dragon sword'   , item: 'weapon'  , value: 5}, 
                        {name: 'a dragon tooth', item: 'amulet' , value: 5},
                        {name: 'a pair of dragon boots'  , item: 'boots'  , value: 4},
                        {name: 'a dragon helmet'  , item: 'helm'  , value: 4}
                    ]
                }
             },

        }

    },
},
```

I want to receive the `_creature_name_`. I saw `foreach` loops with `arrayname.length` but when I try to do `enemy.length` or `enemy.level1.creature.creature_name.length` then I get `undefined`.

Comment: your `creature_name` property is an object, not an array, and therefore doesn't have an intrinsic `length` property of its own

Comment: So how do I loop through it then? @Alnitak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#enemy_list')[0].innerHTML = 'Enemies: <br />Level 1: <br />';
for(var enemy_names in enemy['level1'].creature.creature_name){
    $('#enemy_list')[0].innerHTML += enemy_names + '<br />';
}
```

You need create a prop for the name in`enemy['level1'].creature.creature_name` and then foreach enemy_name place it in the containing div. Goodluck!

By the way, your problem with the for loop was that you executed the `enemies: <br /> level1: <br />` in your `for loop` aswell so it would display it 3 times. This method you put the names inside the div containing the text only once.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted! Places it below each other instead of every name apart inside the text field! thanks

Comment: @GetOn it's not actually what you asked for in _this_ question, though.  It's also poor code because it uses `+=` with `.innerHTML` - always a bad idea because it causes the browser to "serialize" the existing content, then adds to the result string, and then _deserialize_ the entire content again.

Comment: this _is_ what I asked for though. I get every _name_ printed individually on the screen, thats what I asked for. and why is it so bad? Does it cause major bugs / crases etc? Never had any problems with it.

Comment: your question made no mention whatsoever of printing, or HTML - that was only in the comments to my answer.  For why `.innerHTML +=` is bad, see comment above.  It works, but its _nasty_.

Comment: Can you explain me what is better to use @Alnitak so I can update my answer and expend my knowledge?

Comment: @AngelofDemons you should accumulate the content into a single string variable, and only after the loop has finished assign that to the `.innerHTML`.  Or seeing as the OP has jQuery, use that (see my edited answer)

Answer (score 4):

Objects (key/value pairs) don't have an intrinsic `.length` property.

To just get the names as an array you could use:

```
var names = Object.keys(enemy.level1.creature.creature_name);
```

or alternatively to just iterate directly over each name:

```
for (var name in enemy.level1.creature.creature_name) {
    ...
}
```

Regarding the actual content you're after, you could use:

```
$('#enemy_list').html('Enemies: <br/>Level1: <br/>' +
    Object.keys(enemy.level1.creature.creature_name).join('<br/>'));
```

or:

```
var content = ['Enemies:', 'Level1:'].concat(Object.keys(enemy.level1.creature.creature_name));
$('#enemy_list').html(content.join('<br/>'));
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I split them up in 3 different 1 _values_ to place them on the screen _individually_

Comment: @GetOn then you should loop on names i think

Comment: If I loop through it like this: `var names = Object.keys(enemy.level1.creature.creature_name);
 for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  $('#enemy_list')[0].innerHTML += 'Enemies: <br />Level 1: <br />' + names[i] + '<br />';
 }
` It places it individually.But.. for example the result is `dragon , cow , goblin` it places it below each other (which is correct) but ALSO places it 3 times instead of once.

Comment: @GetOn that's really a separate question, for which there is almost certainly already an answer on this site.

Comment: p.s. _never_ use `+=` with `.innerHTML` - make a single string variable and _then_ put that in `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

Since objects don't have length properties assigned to the number of properties inside one solution would be to loop classically through the object as following:

```
for(var prop in enemy['level1'].creature.creature_name){
   console.log(prop)
}
```

This will print out the name one by one

I prepared it in a jsfiddle also: https://jsfiddle.net/fo8xjr8w/

Answer (score 1):

```
var creature_name = enemy.level1.creature.creature_name;

for (var prop in creature_name)
{   
    console.log(prop);
    //this would print Goblin, Cow, Dragon
}
```

You again have to iterate if you want to traverse further internal details for the loot array.

Comment: In modern ES5 code there is absolutely no need to use an `hasOwnProperty` check.